# Búsqueda de registro dentro del rango de horas en un archivo log linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

Tengo mi archivo log */var/log/secure.log* con los siguientes registros:

```
2022-11-11T10:13:16.586508-06:00
 rfs (PID:25135): Selected LNO:13 for T-1.S-151610 dbid 3149211838 branch 1041328339
2022-11-11T12:13:16.827496-06:00
ARC1 (PID:19895): Archived Log entry 44486 added for T-1.S-151609 ID 0xbf247d21 LAD:1
2022-11-12T10:14:41.924128-06:00
 rfs (PID:32409): Selected LNO:14 for T-2.S-128980 dbid 3149211838 branch 1041328339
2022-11-12T10:14:42.008209-06:00
ARC2 (PID:19897): Archived Log entry 44487 added for T-2.S-128979 ID 0xbf247d21 LAD:1
2022-11-13T10:19:04.635669-06:00
 rfs (PID:25135): Selected LNO:16 for T-1.S-151611 dbid 3149211838 branch 1041328339
2022-11-13T10:19:04.829983-06:00
ARC1 (PID:19895): Archived Log entry 44488 added for T-1.S-151610 ID 0xbf247d21 LAD:1
2022-11-13T10:24:07.744536-06:00
 rfs (PID:25135): Selected LNO:13 for T-1.S-151612 dbid 3149211838 branch 1041328339
2022-11-14T10:24:07.927823-06:00
ARC1 (PID:19895): Archived Log entry 44489 added for T-1.S-151611 ID 0xbf247d21 LAD:1
2022-11-14T10:24:42.312711-06:00
 rfs (PID:32409): Selected LNO:15 for T-2.S-128981 dbid 3149211838 branch 1041328339
```

Supongamos que mi hora actual, son las 10:45:00 am del 14/11/2022 tiempo de México y mi último registro fue a las 10:24:42 tiempo México.

Con grep, quiero buscar en ese log todas las líneas que tenga el texto "branch" pero de los últimos 30 minutos. Para ello estoy intentando ocupar el siguiente comando:

```
grep "branch" /var/log/secure.log | date -d "30 min ago"
```

Pero definitivamente no me funciona del todo, como tal solo me imprime la hora de hace 30 minutos atrás.

```
[user@ip-172-31-26-166]# grep "branch" /var/log/secure.log | date -d "30 min ago"
Mon Nov 14 10:15:24 CST 2022
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las marcas de tiempo en su archivo están en ISO-8601, eso está bien.

Lo primero que hay que hacer es determinar la fecha actual y la fecha de hace 30 minutos en el mismo formato.

La fecha actual en ISO-8601:

```bash
date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N-%:z"
```

Hace 30 minutos:

```bash
date --date "30 min ago" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N-%:z"
```

El formato ISO es muy conveniente para las comparaciones de texto (ASCII).

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

awk \
-v end_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N-%:z") \
-v begin_date=$(date --date "30 min ago" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N-%:z") \
'
/branch/ && $1 >= begin_date && $1 <= end_date {
    print
}
' \
< "secure.log"
```

### ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Si las marcas de tiempo no están en las mismas líneas que los datos de registro (que están en una sola línea), el programa es un poco más complicado:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

awk \
-v end_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N-%:z") \
-v begin_date=$(date --date "30 min ago" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N-%:z") \
'
$1 >= begin_date && $1 <= end_date {
    flag=1
    date_line = $0
    next;
}
$1 ~ /^[-0-9]+T[-.:0-9]+$/ {
    flag=0
}
/branch/ && flag == 1 {
    print date_line, $0
}
' \
< "secure.log"
```

Nota: Perdón por mi español

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Aún así, en la pregunta se ha especificado que queria usar  `grep` y también la búsqueda de la cadena `branch`.  ¿Puedes afinar tu respuesta con esas premisas para que lo tenga todo resuelto?  Gracias

Comment: Gracias Arnaud, @masterguru. En realidad esa búsqueda con el grep intento meterlo en un shell script, para que se ejecute cada 30 minutos y si en ese rango me aparece la cadena "branch", la voy a mandar por correo. Bueno esa es mi idea. No se si exista una forma más sencilla o practica, les agradecería mucho

Comment: @Anthony Prueba con esta respuesta de Arnaud, pero en la parte final le cambias `< "secure.log"` por `< "secure.log" | grep -i "branch"`. Seguramente te funcionará.

Comment: Gracias @masterguru ya lo intente, pero no imprime nada. Claro, tengo entendido que la respuesta de Arnaud, va en un archivo shell, correcto?. Tampoco me da devuelve algún error.

Comment: mmm... se habrá equivocado en alguna parte del script... si le quitas el grep que te he dicho te devuelve algo?  Cambiale los treinta minutos por "8 hour ago" a ver si cuela y es un fallo de la diferencia horaria que tienes con el log.  O sea, primero comprueba que algo devuelve alguna vez, y cuando lo consigas entonces le metes el grep de filtro de esos resultados.  Para ejecutarlo entiendo que lo haces con "bash script.sh" o "source script.sh" o "./script.sh" para que te coga el interprete correctamente

Comment: Lo siento, olvidé el filtro de "branch".

Comment: Gracias Arnaud.  @Anthony Cambiando el nombre de las variables de begin_date (por end_date) y end_date (por begin_date) a mi me funciona, pero ojo, porque ahora me doy cuenta que tu log parece que tenga las lineas partidas y he tenido que unir las fechas con el texto de debajo para que funcionara también.

Comment: Gracias. Estoy cansado esta noche :-(
He considerado que la marca de tiempo y los textos asociados están en la misma línea. ¿Una mala interpretación por mi parte?

Comment: No creo, espero que sea un error al ponerlo en la pregunta, porque si no estan en la misma linea va a ser un problema mayor y de peor resolución.  Gracias por tu aporte!

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue sin funcionarme. Estoy tratando de quitar espacios y solo así me arrojo un error:
awk: fatal: cannot open file ` ' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: @Anthony tu ejemplo de archivo `secure` que has puesto en la pregunta divide las lineas del log en dos, donde una es una fecha y la siguiente el texto que le corresponde.  ¿Eso lo tienes así en el archivo `secure` realmente?  ¿o son de una línea?

Comment: Acabo de añadir una versión que puede manejar marcas de tiempo y líneas de datos en diferentes líneas

Comment: @masterguru así lo registra ese archivo.

Comment: Pues actualiza esta página y prueba de nuevo la solución de esta respuesta, a ver si te funciona esta vez. (a mi, para que me funcionara, le puse un `"23 hour ago"` porque la diferencia horaria es mayor aquí, pero eso lo puedes afinar después)

Comment: A mi me funciona estupendamente la nueva actualización de esta respuesta, con las líneas partidas y poniendo lo del las "23 hour ago"

Comment: @ArnaudValmary esta última versión si me funciono. Muchas gracias

Comment: @masterguru igual muchas gracias por el apoyo

Comment: @Anthony Acepta la respuesta si te ha funcionado, Arnaud se lo ha currado muy bien :-)

Comment: @ArnaudValmary disculpa te molesto, ahora necesito validar este formato de log con ese mismo shell:
 `Tue Nov 22 16:30:05 2022

Archived Log entry 57456 added for thread 1 sequence 53234 ID 0x6b28f9cd dest 1: `

Y lo estoy intentando de esta forma:
`$1 ~ /^[A-Za-z]\s[A-Za-z]\s[0-9]\s[-.:0-9]\s20[0-9]{2}+$/ {
    flag=0 }`
Crees que este correcto?

Comment: Es que me traé todas las líneas, desde el inicio de ese registro  hasta la última vez que se escribió.