# Error con el comando awk linux

Tags: shell-script, awk

Tengo un shell script con la instrucción de que me busque un texto en especifico dentro de un archivo log, en un rango de 12 horas.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk \
-v end_date=$(date '+%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y') \
-v begin_date=$(date --date '12 hour ago' '+%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y') \
'
/ORA-/ && $1 >= begin_date && $1 <= end_date {
    print
}
' \
< "/ruta/ruta/alert.log"
```

Al ejecutar, me da el siguiente error:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `17' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

En su momento pense que podría ser el formato de fechas, pero ya lo he modificado y sigo sin poder resolver el error.

Comment: Debes ser cuidadoso con la sintaxis de awk y con cualquier sintaxis... si te fijas en la respuesta que nos dieron en tu [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/568261/263200), esto no lo ponia así: `date '+%a` sinó así: `date +"%Y`... es decir, quita el signo `+` de dentro de las comillas y ponlo delante. Y repasa bien el resto de la sintaxis tal como te la indicaron en esa respuesta, no sea que tengas más fallos de este tipo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### El problema

El problema es que, una vez `$(date)` se ha ejecutado, eso es reemplazado por la fecha actual en el formato que has especificado, por lo que lo que al final le llega al shell es el comando ya expandido, con los resultados de la ejecución de `$(date)`

Por ejemplo, si se ejecuta el 17 nov a las 09:51:25, lo que "verá" el shell es el comando siguiente:

```bash
awk \
-v end_date=Thu Nov 17 21:51:25 2022 \
-v begin_date=Wed Nov 16 21:51:25 2022 \
'
/ORA-/ && $1 >= begin_date && $1 <= end_date { 
    print 
}' \
< "/ruta/ruta/alert.log"
```

Es decir, lo que le estás pasando a `awk` comienza en la forma siguiente:

```
awk -v end_date=Thu Nov 17 21:51:25 2022 ...
```

Los espacios entre "Thu", "Nov", "17", etc... son interpretados como separadores por el shell, por lo que awk está recibiendo muchos parámetros, en concreto:

- `-v` que le indica que seguidamente vendrá una asignación de variable
- `end_date=Thu` que es la asignación de variable que esperaba debido al -v
- `Nov` que es considerado (según la [documentación de awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)) un "program-text", es decir, el nombre de un fichero del que leerá el programa awk a ejecutar.
- `17` que es considerado el nombre del fichero a procesar
- etc... (que serán considerados nombres de ficheros adicionales)

Así que `awk` comienza intentando abrir el fichero a procesar (`17` según lo anterior) y al no encontrarlo te da el error que has visto.

El problema por tanto nace de que el valor que quieres asignar a `end_date` contiene espacios, y el shell usa esos espacios para partirlo en varios argumentos, cuando en realidad quieres que toda la cadena `Thu Nov 17 21:51:25 2022` sea un solo argumento.

### La solución

Para "proteger" un argumento que contenga espacios y evitar que el shell lo "rompa", éste debe encerrarse entre comillas dobles. Por tanto debes modificar el script para que sea así:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk \
-v end_date="$(date '+%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y')" \
-v begin_date="$(date --date '12 hour ago' '+%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y')" \
'
/ORA-/ && $1 >= begin_date && $1 <= end_date { 
    print 
}' \
< "/ruta/ruta/alert.log"
```

### Nota adicional

Me temo que no va a funcionar de todas formas porque, según lo anterior, la variable `begin_date` se inicializaría con una cadena tal que `Thu Nov 17 21:51:25 2022`, pero en tu programa awk comparas esa cadena con `$1`, y la comparación no va a funcionar puesto que `$1` sería el primer "token" de la línea del fichero, y los tokens se consideran delimitados por espacios. Por tanto, aún si el fichero contiene una línea que comienza por `Thu Nov 17 21:51:25 2022`, el token `$1` tendría el valor `Thu`

Deberías proporcionar un ejemplo del contenido del log para entender mejor qué pretendes hacer.

Comment: Gracias, eran las comillas.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que se refiere a la respuesta del artículo : [Búsqueda de registro dentro del rango de horas en un archivo log linux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/568248/b%c3%basqueda-de-registro-dentro-del-rango-de-horas-en-un-archivo-log-linux)

### Primer error:

En tu formato de fecha (%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y), tienes espacios, y por lo tanto, en la línea de comandos de awk, la asignación a los parámetros `end_date` y `begin_date` será sólo con el valor del `%a`. ¡El resto de las fechas (`17`) y otros trozos de fechas, se interpretarán como parámetros adicionales a AWK y serán interpretados por AWK como nombres de ficheros!
Solución:
Poner comillas alrededor del comando `date`:

```bash
...
-v end_date="$(date '+%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y')" \
-v begin_date="$(date --date '12 hour ago' '+%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y')" \
...
```

### Segundo error:

El formato de fecha tal y como lo usas no es apropiado para hacer la comparación de fechas como cadenas ASCII con los operadores AWK `>`, `<`, `>=` y `<=`.

Orden correcto: %Y > %m > %d > %H > %M > %S > %N

Siempre debe formatear sus fechas de la unidad más grande a la más pequeña. No debe utilizar un formato "humanamente" legible (día de la semana o mes en palabras, `%a`, `%b`...).

Utilice siempre formatos en los que el resultado sea siempre la misma longitud. No utilice `%e` sino `%m`, `%k` sino `%H`....

Si las fechas de su archivo están en el formato `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y`, deben ser trabajadas antes de la comparación. ¿Cuál es el formato de su archivo de entrada? ¿Puede poner algunas líneas de ejemplo en su consulta?

Nota: Perdón por mi español